# Postscript. Get document page size

Tags: java, postscript

I wish to take page size of document, such as A4, A5, A6 etc.

Solution, which I found it's parsing of postscript text and extracting string `A6` from

```
featurebegin{
%%BeginFeature: *PageSize A6

    <</DeferredMediaSelection true /PageSize  [298 420] /ImagingBBox null /MediaClass null>> setpagedevice
%%EndFeature
}featurecleanup
```

but this works slowly...

How I can do this? Do exist any libraries for getting full document information?

I prefer solutions in java, if exists.

Comment: Find yourself a copy of the official *PostScript Language Reference*. A "PostScript" file, in general, does not have (nor need!) to mention a page size, although a physical page size may be "assumed during the generation of this page description" (from ref.), and this usually are the dimensions in points, not by name as you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution there only works for a DSC (Document Structure Convention) conforming file. While many files do conform, others do not. Also that only works if the PostScript file contains a comment (% introduces a comment in PostScript).

You could instead override the setpagedevice operator and have it print the requested media size if present.

```
/Oldsetpagedevice /setpagedevice load def

/setpagedevice {
  dup /PageSize known {
    dup /PageSize get
    dup 0 get 20 string cvs exch 1 get 20 string cvs exch
    (Requested Media Size is ) print print (points by ) print print (points\n) print
  } if
  Oldsetpagedevice
} bind def
```

What do you mean by 'full document information' ? By the way, you need to be aware that (unlike PDF) PostScript files are programs, not documents. So the **only** way to know what's really going on is to interpret the program.

You could use Ghostscript, but it does not have a Java interface, and you would need to be much  more specific about the information you want.

Comment: FYI, `DeferredMediaSelection` is described in the PLRM that I have (3rd ed.), but of course there is no guarantee the document contains this. (@Sergey: it's useful for you because its `/PageSize` value is what I mentioned above: the size in points.)

Comment: Ghostscript can, with sufficient programming, deliver all kinds of information. Like I said, what do you want to know ? One of the points about using a PostScript interpreter is that it can find the information even when its not in comments, or is buried in a procedure. grep and friends will not be able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the postscript through ghostscript with `-sDEVICE=bbox` it would report the corners of a rectangle which crops the rendered output, which may be (close to) what you want.

The info is usually printed to `stderr` in a DSC `%%BoundingBox: x0 y0 x1 y1` format.